# Problems with classes and types

Tags: c++, class, types

I have a class that I'm trying to use as a type

```
class ship{
    public:
        vector <int> xp;
        vector <int> yp;
        vector <bool> pos;
        shipType vessel;
        bool active;
    ship(){}
    void randommethods(){
        blah;
    }
};
```

I want to include in a fleet class an array of type ship.

```
class fleet{
    public:
        ship boat[7];
    boat(){}
};
```

I've included the a header file for ship.h in the source file for fleet but it doesn't recognize ship as a type.

```
fleet.cpp:12: error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of ‘boat’ with no type
fleet.cpp:13: error: declaration of ‘int fleet::boat()’
fleet.cpp:11: error: conflicts with previous declaration ‘ship fleet::boat [7]’
```

I can use a similar declaration to work with a variable of type ship and all of the member methods within ship.cpp. What am I doing wrong any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code for fleet class you declare an `array of ship`( shop boat[7] ) named boat AND a `function member returning int` ( boat(){} ) named boat. You try to declare two distinct entities with the same name in one namespace and this is error. That what compiler tries to tell you.

I guess you wanted to wright a default constructor for fleet class smth like this:

```
class fleet{
    public:
        ship boat[7];
    fleet(){} //fleet, not boat
};
```

Comment: Thanks I can't believe I didn't see that. It's had me hung up for the last 45 min.